# Script says "Site doesn´t exist" when trying to upload to SharePoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I got a script which uploads all files from a Folder to SharePoint-site:

```
asnp "*sh*"

$url=Read-Host "Enter Site Url" 
$web=Get-SPWeb -Identity $url

if($web)
{
    try
    {
        $list = $web.Lists.TryGetList("Documents")
        $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Manju" -Force -Recurse

        foreach ($file in $files)
        {
            $stream = $file.OpenRead()
            $done= $list.RootFolder.Files.Add($file.Name, $stream, $true)
            Write-Host $done.Name  "Uploaded into the Site" -BackgroundColor Green         
        }
    }

    catch
    {
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        Write-Host $ErrorMessage -BackgroundColor Yellow 
    }
}

asnp "*sh*"

$url=Read-Host "Enter Site Url"  
$web=Get-SPWeb -Identity $url  

if($web)
{   
    try   
    {
        $list = $web.Lists.TryGetList("Documents")  
        $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Manju" -Force -Recurse  

        foreach ($file in $files)   
        {    
            $stream = $file.OpenRead()   
            $done= $list.RootFolder.Files.Add($file.Name, $stream, $true)   
            Write-Host $done.Name  "Uploaded into the Site" -BackgroundColor Green            
        }   
    }   
    catch    
    {   
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message   
        Write-Host $ErrorMessage -BackgroundColor Yellow     
    }    
}   
else   
{    
    Write-Host "Site Doesn't exist"   
}

$list.Update();else
{
    Write-Host "Site Doesn't exist"
}
    $list.Update();
```

If I run it and put the url inside prompt (http://teams-test.xxxxx.com/sites/projects/Business/prints/Houseprints/Forms/AllItems.aspx) it always says

> Write-Host "Site Doesn't exist"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run the script under a user account that has enough privileges. It has to have direct access to the content database where the site is located and, of course, the configuration database as well.

Comment: Hello naivists, I checked that and it´s always the same (admin) account which also has direct access to the content database and it also has enough privileges.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs since [Get-SPWeb cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607807(v=office.15).aspx) expects a valid web site url to be provided.

In your case instead of  **list view** url  that is specified as a parameter for a Get-SPWeb, please try to specify web url: `http://teams-test.xxxxx.com/sites/projects/Business/prints/`

Update

It seems the account does not have necessary privileges to the SharePoint object model and to the SharePoint databases. Please follow [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490648.aspx) to set Privileges for Using PowerShell to Manage SharePoint.

For example, to provide access to all content databases and SharePoint service application databases the following command could be used:

```
Get-SPDatabase | Add-SPShellAdmin DOMAIN\username
```

Comment: Hello Vadim, I noticed that too and tried that, but it´s the exact same error.

Comment: It seems the account does not have necessary privileges to the SharePoint object model and to the SharePoint databases from PowerShell, the answer has been updated